# Rebuild Intel Rapid Storage RAID 10

Tags: raid, hardware-raid, intel-rst

I recently moved and decided to transport my hard drives separately from the rest of my computer (to avoid hard drive vibration damage).

Unfortunately, I forgot the order the drives were in and now my RAID won't show up anymore. Is there any way to recover my data/the RAID array?

Comment: The easiest method would be to restore from backups

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have backups